# Cannot scm git pull jenkinsfile from private commit on gerrit

Tags: jenkins, version-control, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Team,
I want to pull the Jenkinsfile from my private commit which is on private branch on gerrit server. When i set it to main pull works but somehow pull of commit is not working.

[image: Jenkins_GUI_Setting]
steps

- I cloned main
- created a private branch
- pushed `Jenkinsfile` as a commit to this private branch
- added scm config as shown in jenkins gui.

but i am observing that it is not finding my commit. any hint what could be missing in my jenkins gui config? or is this not supported and jenkinsfile needs to be on main branch of the repo?

`Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.`

error i get on jenkins log is

```
Checking out git ssh://svc-repo_test-team-sa@git-av.company.com:12013/repo_test into /var/jenkins/workspace/repo_test/code-coverage-stage@script/7d000137d1c23eb647ed5a846ade258380196b11b7142f8fc6bebd5f9c212d93 to read src/jenkins/ci/Jenkinsfile
The recommended git tool is: git
using credential git-av-repo_test-ci-ssh
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins/workspace/repo_test/code-coverage-stage@script/7d000137d1c23eb647ed5a846ade258380196b11b7142f8fc6bebd5f9c212d93/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://svc-repo_test-team-sa@git-av.company.com:12013/repo_test # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://svc-repo_test-team-sa@git-av.company.com:12013/repo_test
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.30.2'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials git-av-repo_test-ci-ssh
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- ssh://svc-repo_test-team-sa@git-av.company.com:12013/repo_test +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse b2c27446fdccb414fb1e92984d528179babf5e78^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/b2c27446fdccb414fb1e92984d528179babf5e78^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse b2c27446fdccb414fb1e92984d528179babf5e78^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
```

config on jenkins gui is

```
SCM: git
Branches to build: commit_sha_id << here if I put MAIN it checksout repo but does not work be
Script Path: src/jenkins/ci/Jenkinsfile
```

sample Jenkinsfile

```
def checkoutRepo(containerName = 'main') {
    container(containerName) {
        sh 'rm -rf archive; rm -rf tmp'
            checkout(
                [
                    $class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: '$GERRIT_REFSPEC']],
                    // branches: [[name: params.COMMIT_SHA_ID]],
                    extensions: [[
                        $class: 'BuildChooserSetting',
                        buildChooser: [$class: 'GerritTriggerBuildChooser'],
                    ],
                        [$class: 'CloneOption', shallow: true, noTags: true, depth: 2, honorRefspec: true]
                    ],
                    // userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[
                        credentialsId: 'git-product-ci-ssh',
                        name: 'origin',
                        refspec: '+$GERRIT_REFSPEC:$GERRIT_REFSPEC',
                        url: 'ssh://svc-product-org-sa@git.company.com:120/product']
                    ]
                ]
            )
    } 
}

def bazelInit(containerName = 'main') {
    container(containerName) {
        withCredentials([
            string(credentialsId: 'product-ci-build-cache-jwt', variable: 'CACHE_TOKEN'),
            usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'artifactory-build-suborg-ai-bazel', usernameVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_USER', passwordVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN')
        ]) {
            sh '''
                BUILDAUTH_SILENT=1 ./buildauth static
                set +e
                BUILD_ID=nokill BUILD_TAG=nokill BUILD_VERSION=nokill BUILD_NUMBER= ./bazel version
                if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                    ./bazel shutdown || true
                fi
            '''.stripIndent()
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'product-verify'
    }
    options {
        // ansiColor('xterm')
        parallelsAlwaysFailFast()
        buildDiscarder( logRotator( artifactDaysToKeepStr: '30', artifactNumToKeepStr: '100', daysToKeepStr: '30', numToKeepStr: '100'))
        throttleJobProperty(
            throttleEnabled: true,
            throttleOption: 'project',
            maxConcurrentPerNode: 1,
            maxConcurrentTotal: 20,
          )
    }
    parameters {
        booleanParam( name: 'Refresh', defaultValue: false, description: 'Reload job from the Jenkinsfile and then exit')
        string( name: 'GERRIT_CREDENTIALS_ID', defaultValue: 'git-product-ci-http', description: 'Gerrit credentials')
        string( name: 'GERRIT_API_URL', defaultValue: 'https://git.company.com/r', description: 'Gerrit API URL')
        string(name: 'COMMIT_SHA_ID', defaultValue: '', description: 'commit ID')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {

                preBuild(bazel_init)
                script {
                  bazel_init = false
                }
            }
        }


        stage('Code Scan') {
            agent {
                label 'product-coverage-cli'
            }
            when { expression { !params.Refresh } }

            steps {
                checkoutRepo()
                bazelInit()
                container('main') {
                                                    sh '''
                        echo "Running on STAGE git"
                        sonar-scanner -v
                        echo "installed sonar scanner!"                                
                        echo "Start scan"
                        src/jenkins/ci/code-scan-all.sh
                        '''.stripIndent()
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `*/main` branch in job configured, and try the following workaround:

```
parameters { string(name: 'COMMIT_SHA_ID', defaultValue: '', description: 'commit ID') }

...
stages {
 stage('Checkout') {
  steps { 
   script { 
    if (params.COMMIT_SHA_ID?.trim()) {
      echo "Build from ${params.COMMIT_SHA_ID}"
      checkout([
         $class: 'GitSCM',
         branches: [[name: params.COMMIT_SHA_ID]],
         userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs])
      }
    } else {
       echo "Build from main"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

> Might require a whitelisting/permission by an administrator to accessing `scm` fields.

Comment: you mean create a string parameter `COMMIT_SHA_ID` on gui and change my Jenkins file to above code?

Comment: i tried. it still tries to get from MAIN and not from my commit and complains `Jenkinsfile` not found.

Comment: Can u share ur jenkinsfile, is expected to get from main branche before run the checkout stage